# Wrong use of execlp function

Tags: c, unix

I tried to write C program in Unix environment that uses the `execlp` function. I am executing the `tsort` command (tsort gets a text file as a input).

```
void syserr(char * str)
{
    perror(str);
    exit(1);
}
int main()
{
    int inpfd;
    int pipeC[2];
    char buffer[4];
    execlp("tsort","tsort","t.txt");
    syserr("execlp  ");
}
```

the error is :

```
tsort: extra operand 'AWA\211\377AVI\211\366AUI\211\325ATL\215%\350\a '
Try 'tsort --help' for more information.
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [the manual on `execlp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp)

> [...] The list of arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer, and, since these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast *(char *) NULL*.

You're not doing that. Try:

```
execlp("tsort","tsort","t.txt",(char*)NULL);
```